# SQL CE and C# Application

Tags: sql, c#-4.0

There is a project I'm off to start and thinking of using SQL CE to keep resources small and anyway the data would be simple enough.

I was thinking and "heard" that there is a way that u can make your app play with SQL CE without installing the runtime, with adding some dlls and voila.

I would like to start using EF4 so it would be EF4 on SQL CE.

Any points, thought?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just deploy the binaries that can be found in the installed directory on your development PC - meaning anyone using your app doesn't need to run an MSI for it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983326(VS.80).aspx

I don't know much about EF4 and SQL-CE, but I spotted this after a short search:

http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/a-few-sql-server-ce-and-entity-framework-gotchas/